# Custom redirect from AuthorizationHandler (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm using an authentication middleware that is making API requests to a third party service. This middleware then sets up the claims that are later handled by an AuthorizationHandler in conjunction with a IAuthorizationRequirement and a custom policy.

The middleware piece works and I'm able to build the claims:

```
context.User.AddIdentity(identity); // contains claims
```

Where I'm stuck is redirecting to a specific URL (there are custom rules for where we need to redirect) from the handler or attribute. From the handler I tried:

```
var mvcContext = context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;
mvcContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("login", "home", null);
```

but it's ignored; only a 401 is returned. `AuthorizeAttribute` no longer has OnAuthorization so I can't use that either...

Thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your approach with the AuthorizationFilterContext in the handler was almost correct. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46108155/5168962) you need to also say `context.Succeed(requirement);` for it to work.

So complete solution would be something like this:

1. Create a custom Requirement:

   ```
   public class SomeCustomRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
   {}
   ```
2. Create a custom Handler:

   ```
   public class SomeCustomRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SomeCustomRequirement>
   {
       protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserInformationCompletedRequirement requirement)
       {
           if (!fulfillsRequirement())
               if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext redirectContext)
                   redirectContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/Unauthorized");
               // even though this is weird it is necessary
               context.Succeed(requirement);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register the handler:

   ```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy(IdentityConstants.UserInformationCompletePolicy, policy =>
       {
           policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
           policy.Requirements.Add(new SomeCustomRequirement());
       });
   });

   services.AddSingelton<IAuthorizationHandler, SomeCustomRequirementHandler>();    
   // OR transient if the handler uses the Entity Framework
   services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, SomeCustomRequirementHandler>();
   ```

Even though my answer is late I hope it might help future visitors.

Comment: if anyone comes here now with .net 6+ this doesn't work.
You need:

[]if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
                {
                  httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Errors/Unauthorized");
                  context.Succeed(requirement);
                }

Comment: @punkologist You're right, context.Resource was changed to HttpContext. But `httpContext.Response.Redirect` doesn't work for me. Is it working for you without any additional chagnes?

Comment: I know this is an old one, but I found that returning the context.Succeed with the redirect causes the controller action to run first and then redirect to the unauthorized page which could cause some action code to run which shouldn't. So I'm not sure what the more correct way would be to handle this? Doing context.Fail just gives them a 403 error without doing the redirect. I can't find anything about how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want to attempt in your API's Middleware is to perform a LogIn behaviour, **as your code seems to explain**, these possible cases are, in my opinion, thought-provoking :

1. If `/login/home` redirects to a webpage:

   - You should use `HttpContext.Response.Redirect` to redirect to the LogIn webpage. [As the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponse_Redirect_System_String_), This would send a 301 code that any web browser can interpret. The HttpContext is available in the `Invoke` method.
2. If `/login/home` redirects to a controller that performs logic that validates user identity:

   - You can instead validate the identity of your user inside the middleware rather than in a separate route. [Just like the great Nate Barbettini does](https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider/blob/c013de70e9704ca3f5ba027944f18f4d697de261/src/SimpleTokenProvider/TokenProviderMiddleware.cs).

Take also a look at [Nate's post](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

As [Brent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045215/brent-kilboy) said, calling `context.Succeed(requirement)` will *not* exit the middleware pipeline, so the controller will end up returning a body along with the redirect. This is a pretty big security issue as it can return sensitive content.

A solution my team went with is to

- call `context.Fail()` which will correctly exit the middleware pipeline

  - This will set the response code to 401
- add a middleware *above* authentication that checks for a 401, and changes it to a redirect.

```cs
app.Use(
    async (context, next) =>
    {
        // note: headers might be sent before middleware ends otherwise
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        // call the rest of the auth middleware
        await next();
        if (
            context.Response.StatusCode == 401
            && (
                context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/your-route")
            )
        )
        {
            // change the response to a normal redirect.
            // could assert the response body is empty. 
            context.Response.StatusCode = 302;
            context.Response.Redirect("/LogIn");
        }
    }
);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```