# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Redirecting user from AuthorizationHandler, HandleRequirementAsync method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to implement AuthorizationHandler in .net core 2.0 where i need to authorize the user and based on the condition wanted to redirect to different action methods within my application validation works ok but how i can redirect user to the Access Denied or Login page when authorization failed.

```
 protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasPermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        var controllerContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;

        if (sessionManager.Session.sysUserID <= 0)
        {
            controllerContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", area = "" }));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }


            if (Utilities.GetInt32Negative(PermissionID) == 1 || Utilities.GetInt32Negative(PermissionID) == -1)
            {
                if (!PagePath.Equals("~/"))
                    controllerContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "NoAccess", area = "" }));
            }

            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!PagePath.Equals("~/"))
                controllerContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "NoAccess", area = "" }));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Comment: You are not supposed to be doing redirects from authorization requirements. Setup your authentication handler to redirect to the correct pages for when authorization fails. This is usually done in `Startup`, where you define which authentication methods you support etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution and i hope this will help someone looking for the similar, in custom authorization we can redirect to any desired controller action using the **AuthorizationFilterContext** and with the **RedirectToActionResult**

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasPermissionRequirement requirement)
{
    // Get the context       
    var redirectContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
    //check the condition 
    if (!result)
    {
        redirectContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", "Home", null);
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    context.Succeed(requirement);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: do mention the class to be extended before overriding

Comment: @NevilleNazerane class to be extended is `AuthorizationHandler<T>`.

Comment: In my application, it's working for published project but not working on debug mode.  What could be the reason?

Comment: In .NET Core 6, I am getting null on `redirectContext`.

Comment: if anyone comes here now with .net 6+ this doesn't work. You need: []if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext) { httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Errors/Unauthorized"); context.Succeed(requirement); } @dev

Comment: I know this is an old one, but I found that returning the context.Succeed with the redirect causes the controller action to run first and then redirect to the unauthorized page which could cause some action code to run which shouldn't. So I'm not sure what the more correct way would be to handle this? Doing context.Fail just gives them a 403 error without doing the redirect. I can't find anything about how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1):

First you can configure the conditions for login page/authentication by creating a custom scheme like this.

```
public class SampleScheme : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public const string SchemeName = "sample";

    public SampleScheme(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
                    : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (myconditions){
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("error message");
        }
        else {
            return await Context.AuthenticateAsync
            (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); 
           // return default cookie functionality. 
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can create a similar class for Access denied/forbidden access as well (lets say `SampleScheme2`). 
Finally you can set them up in your startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = SampleScheme.SchemeName;
    options.DefaultForbidScheme = SampleScheme2.SchemeName;
})
.AddCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/forbidden";
})
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, SampleScheme>(SampleScheme.SchemeName, o => { });
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, SampleScheme2>(SampleScheme2.SchemeName, o => { });
```

I hope the code is self explanatory enough. There are some variations so let me know if this is not exactly what you were going for.

Answer (score 1):

Related to @Azhar's answer, but applicable for .NET 6.
It seems that `AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource` no longer pattern matches to  `AuthorizationFilterContext`. A runtime error reveals that the Type is now `DefaultHttpContext`. Following this, the `Redirect(string, bool)` method on the `HttpResponse` can be used for `AuthorizationHandler`-specific routing.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasPermissionRequirement requirement)
{
    //Get the context
    var httpContext = context.Resource as DefaultHttpContext;

    //check the condition 
    if (!result)
    {
        //Set redirect
        httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/AccessDenied", permanent: true);
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    context.Succeed(requirement);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

References:

- [HttpContext.Redirect(string, bool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.redirect?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpresponse-redirect(system-string))
- [HttpContext.Redirect examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0)