# ASP.NET CORE 3.1 How to redirect from HandleRequirementAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and `context.Resource` as `AuthorizationFilterContext` cannot be used to access the `routeValues` or `queryString`. I have to use `IHttpContextAccessor` to get the `routeValues["id"]` but `IHttpContextAccessor` does not have `Result` property to set `RedirectToPage("/View", new {id = "...."})`

```
public class NoEditOrDeleteSuperUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ManageSuperAdminRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;        

    public NoEditOrDeleteSuperUserHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        this._userManager = userManager;            
    }
    
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ManageSuperAdminRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userId =  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["id"].ToString();
        
        var selectedUser = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        
        
        if (_userManager.IsInRoleAsync(selectedUser,"SuperAdmin").GetAwaiter().GetResult() == false)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        context.Fail();
        var Response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
        var message= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("User with Super Admin role cannot be edited");
        
        
        **// return RedirectToPage("/View", new {id = id});**

        Response.OnStarting(async () =>
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
            await Response.Body.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);
        });
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I am using Custom Policy Authorization and when Authorization fails I want to redirect the user to `returnUrl` instead of Access Denied page

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46108155/12282249

Comment: Context.Resource can't be converted to AuthorizationFilterContext it returns null. I have tried this solution before. I have to inject IHttpContextAccessor to access the queryStrings

Answer (score 0):

I found myself a solution to my above question regarding how to redirect a user to referer page after having a failed Custom Authorization check.

**Please if there is any better way to do this please guide me.**

1 - I removed the below code from `HandleRequirementAsync` and let it redirect to AccessDenied Page.

```
    var Response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
    var message= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("User with Super Admin role cannot be edited");


    **// return RedirectToPage("/View", new {id = id});**

    Response.OnStarting(async () =>
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        await Response.Body.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);
    });
```

2 - In AccessDeniedModel class I added below code:

```
    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = "Access Denied: You do not have access to this resource.";
        HttpContext.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"]);
    }
```

4 - In /User/Roles/View.cshtml.cs I defined a model public property

```
    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }
```

3 - In /User/Roles/View.cshtml I added `<p>@Model.Message</p>` to display the message to the user.