# Custom Authorization ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to create a simple authorization handler that redirects the user to a specific page when requirement is not fulfilled like so:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        AdminRequirement requirement)
{
    if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (!context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Denied");
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }            

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I followed [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707051/custom-redirect-from-authorizationhandler-asp-net-core) but `context.Resource` is of type `RouteEndpoint` not `HttpContext`. The main target is to redirect the user to a resource I specified when authorization is not fulfilled.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
{
    if (!context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Denied");
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

to

```
if (!httpContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Denied");
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
```

And you also need to
below code

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Options.Role), // <-- need to add  this line
```